# Serial chart which starts from 0 if only positive values are present, but accepts negatives as well

Tags: javascript, amcharts

So basically I need a serial chart, but if only positives are entered, no mattter what values they have, then the chart would always show 0 as a base value and if in case there are any negative values, then to display them as well.
If I use the "minimum" property for ValueAxis and set it to zero, this prevents the chart from displaying negatives, while the "baseValue" set to 0, doesn't force the chart to use 0 as a base at all times, but caluclates based on the values that are passed.
Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/b3kyos6g/

```
"valueAxes": [{
  "position": "left",
  "title": "Visitors",
  "baseValue": 0,
}],
```

Just change the negative value to a positive one (remove the -)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation probably isn't clear on how `baseValue` works. `baseValue`  is used to redefine the "zero line", meaning that area graph fills will go to that value, and columns start at that value. It has nothing to do with the scale or minimum/maximums of the axis.

To make the chart automatically start from zero if your values are all positive, you can write a mini-plugin using [`AmCharts.addInitHandler`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCharts#addInitHandler) to check your data values and set the minimum as appropriate prior to the chart's initialization, like so:

```
// Mini plugin to force a zero minimum on the first value axis if all values
// are non-negative. Can be extended to support multiple value axes if needed.
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {
  //get all value fields if there are multiple graphs
  var valueFields = chart.graphs.map(function(graph) {
    return graph.valueField;
  });
  //find out if there are any negative values in the dataProvider for any graph.
  var containsNegatives = chart.dataProvider.some(function(dataItem) {
    return valueFields.some(function(valueField) {
      return dataItem[valueField] < 0;
    });
  });

  //only set the value axis minimum to 0 if there are no negatives.
  if (!containsNegatives) {
    chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = 0;
    chart.validateData();
  }
}, ['serial']);
```

Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3kyos6g/2/) that demonstrates this using two charts.